# Bolt CMS Unknown Cache Error

Tags: lamp, php-5.3, bolt-cms

I'm getting this error on every page, using Bolt cms:

```
Error: Uncaught exception 'Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException' with message 
'Error opening file Could not lock app/cache/config_cache.php for writing! 

Try logging in with your ftp-client and check to see if it is chmodded to be readable by the webuser (ie: 777 or 766, depending on the setup of your server). 

Current path: /chroot/home/alumctr/[intentionally hidden]/html.' in   vendor/silex/silex/src/Silex/Application.php:378
Stack trace:
#0 src/Library.php(319): Silex\Application->abort(401, 'Error opening f...')
#1 src/Config.php(753): Bolt\Library::saveSerialize('/chroot/home/al...', Array)
#2 src/Config.php(44): Bolt\Config->saveCache()
#3 src
File: vendor/silex/silex/src/Silex/Application.php
Line: 378
```

The cache folder is empty and has 777 permission.

Where could this error comiming from?

Thank you all

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is the way your `chroot` is set up.

Error is being caused be a file operation that needs `lock` access to write out that file and that is separate to PHP itself.

Initially try running your web set up outside of a `chroot` gaol to get it working and step through from there.

Answer (score 0):

Try giving permissions to that folder.

Here is a BOLT CMS doc about just that.

https://docs.bolt.cm/3.1/installation/permissions